# Possible nullptr dereference in hash queue insertion of Linux v0.11

Tags: linux-kernel

I noticed that there's possibly a nullptr dereference in the source code of Linux v0.11. In line 163 of *buffer.c*, `bh->b_next` could be NULL, especially when the hash queue is empty. Therefore the `bh->b_next->b_prev = bh;` would be a nullptr dereference. Is it?

```c
static inline void insert_into_queues(struct buffer_head * bh)
{
/* put at end of free list */
    bh->b_next_free = free_list;
    bh->b_prev_free = free_list->b_prev_free;
    free_list->b_prev_free->b_next_free = bh;
    free_list->b_prev_free = bh;
/* put the buffer in new hash-queue if it has a device */
    bh->b_prev = NULL;
    bh->b_next = NULL;
    if (!bh->b_dev)
        return;
    bh->b_next = hash(bh->b_dev,bh->b_blocknr);
    hash(bh->b_dev,bh->b_blocknr) = bh;
    bh->b_next->b_prev = bh;
}
```

Hope someone can tell me whether I'm right or wrong.

Comment: It is fully possible. It was version 0.11, so do not expect quality or bug free. Linus admitted that he was a very bad C programmer at beginning, doing a lot of newbie errors (e.g. not guarding macros with parentheses). So look such version of Linux just in historical context, not as correct/well engineered code.